# Debugger not working with pycharm PyCharm 2019.2 (Community Edition)

Tags: pycharm

I am working with PyCharm 2019.2 (Community Edition). Initially, before the update, debugger was working all fine but once it got updated to 2019.2 (Community Edition), every time I hit the debugger for a Django app, it comes up with

```
  File "/home/ujjwal.sharan/environments/ondemand/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 97, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
  File "/home/ujjwal.sharan/environments/ondemand/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 323, in main
    reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/ujjwal.sharan/environments/ondemand/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 294, in python_reloader
    exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
  File "/home/ujjwal.sharan/environments/ondemand/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 280, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = os.spawnve(os.P_WAIT, sys.executable, args, new_environ)
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/143/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 496, in new_spawnve
    return getattr(os, original_name)(mode, path, args, env)
  File "/home/ujjwal.sharan/environments/ondemand/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 573, in spawnve
    return _spawnvef(mode, file, args, env, execve)
  File "/home/ujjwal.sharan/environments/ondemand/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 549, in _spawnvef
    elif WIFSIGNALED(sts):
  File "/home/ujjwal.sharan/environments/ondemand/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 549, in _spawnvef
    elif WIFSIGNALED(sts):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is known PyCharm [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/PY-36726). There they suggest checking "No reload" under the Debug Configuration.

Comment: Sorry but i am not able to find any such option in the debug configuration which points to "No reload".

Answer (score 0):

I have got a similar issue with **Version 2021.2 community edition**, no solution worked except for downgrading it to 2021.1.3

And I have no real problems with the previous version as I am working with it for some time. If you had no luck with any fixes available out there, please try downgrading to the previous version or perhaps upgrading to next subsequent version from the current upgrade (if available)